# What's the correct OID for an array of composite type in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5, postgresql-9.6

Under PostgreSQL 9.5, in a C function I wrote, `ARR_ELEMTYPE(PG_GETARG_ARRAYTYPE_P(0))` where (0) is an array of composite type (i.e. defined by `CREATE TYPE`) returned 28642010. This number doesn't appear in the source code and is undocumented.

Today, I upgraded to PG 9.6 and my C function threw an error. The elemtype is now reported as 16396. This also does not appear in the source code.

I searched both numbers in decimal and hex in both the wiki and the source.

I can't see how a) the OID isn't defined in the source code and b) the number changes with a change of PG.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: `select oid from pg_type where typname = '...'`?

Comment: Yup, that gives the new number, 16396.

Comment: I think I figured it out. That OID varies because the DB had to be recreated due to the changes in 9.6. That is going to make it very interesting to get this consistent in C.

Comment: So inside your C code you need to lookup the OID from the database, not hardcode it.

Comment: That's what I figured. Wasn't expecting such a code overhead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Oid of any object you create in a database, including a type, is assigned by the system and will change if you dump the database and restore it to a different one.

To figure out the Oid of a type in a C function from its name and the Oid of its schema, you can do something like this:

```
typoid = GetSysCacheOid2(TYPENAMENSP,
                         CStringGetDatum(typeName),
                         ObjectIdGetDatum(typeNamespace));
```

Comment: Thank you. That's much more elegant that using SPI to query it.

Comment: I'm just trying this in code now. I'm not clear as to which value to put for the first param. Could you give an example, please?

Comment: I look in the source, and it gives the first param as "cacheId". I'm not sure what that is. Also, since this function requires the typeNamespace, surely I'd need to look that up to using a similar function to this?

Comment: You need to `#include "utils/syscache.h"` for `TYPENAMENSP`. If you don't need the schema (there is only one such type in the database), you could try `GetSysCacheOid1(TYPENAMENSP, CStringGetDatum(typeName))`

Comment: GetSysCacheOid1 doesn't work. Will typnamespace always be 2200 for user-defined types?

Comment: Can you describe *doesn't work*? `typnamespace` will be the `Oid` of the schema that contains the type. If that is `public`, it will be 2200, unless somebody dropped and recreated it... But you should use `PG_PUBLIC_NAMESPACE` defined in `catalog/pg_namespace.h` instead of 2200; it might change some day.

Comment: Doesn't work = returns 0. PG_PUBLIC_NAMESPACE... perfect! Obviously other namespaces would have to be looked up. For my reference, how would I do that?

Comment: With `GetSysCacheOid1(NAMESPACENAME, CStringGetDatum(nspname))`

Comment: Thank you, Laurenz. You are very helpful :)

Comment: Is there a way to retrieve the current namespace?

Comment: What is the current namespace? :^) You can use `fetch_search_path(bool includeImplicit)` from `catalog/namespace.h` to get a `List` of namespaces on the `search_path`. BTW, I just found the simpler `get_namespace_oid` in `catalog/namespace.h` to get the `Oid` for a namespace.

Comment: By current namespace, I mean the namespace the function is in.

Comment: `Oid procGetNapespace(Oid funcOid) { Relation relation; HeapTuple tup; Oid nspoid; relation = heap_open(ProcedureRelationId, RowShareLock); tup = SearchSysCache1(PROCOID, ObjectIdGetDatum(funcOid)); if (!HeapTupleIsValid(tup)) elog(ERROR, "cache lookup failed for function %u", funcOid); nspoid = ((Form_pg_proc) GETSTRUCT(tup))->pronamespace; heap_close(relation, RowShareLock); return nspoid; }`

Answer (score 1):

Laurenz's answer is correct, but no longer compiles on Postgres 14. `GetSysCacheOid*` family of functions requires additional argument.

To get OID of a type it should now be:

```
typeOid = GetSysCacheOid2(TYPENAMENSP,
                          Anum_pg_type_oid,
                          CStringGetDatum(typeName),
                          ObjectIdGetDatum(typeNamespace));
```

To get OID of a namespace:

```
namespaceOid = GetSysCacheOid1(NAMESPACENAME,
                               Anum_pg_namespace_oid,
                               CStringGetDatum(namespaceName));
```